# Algorithm to get the number of sorted combinations?

Tags: combinatorics

Lets have a set of number S = {A,B,C,...,n} where A < B < C .... < n
how many ways can you sort their combinations?

Take this small example:

If the set is {1,2,8} (so n = 3) i can sort their combination in ascending order like this: 1,2,1+2,8,1+8,2+8,1+2+8 which is equal to: A,B,C,A+B,A+C,B+C,A+B+C
BUT if my set of numbers is 1,3,4 then my array will be equal to: A,B,A+B,C,A+C,B+C,A+B+C  as you can see A+B will be greater or smaller sometimes.

So for N = 3 theres the follow possible combinations:
{A,B,C,A+B,A+C,B+C,A+B+C} and {A,B,A+B,C,A+C,B+C,A+B+C} theres only 2

Is there an algorithm that can take out for me this combinations(dont brute force)?
How many combinations are in N, 
i want to know how many "combinations" can i get, so for N = 3 its 2 for N = 3 its ???.

Thanks.

Comment: a+b  is not greater than c in the 1,3,4 case, a=1; b=3; a+b=4; c=4

Comment: Presumably, you want positive numbers - otherwise, you can get $A+B+C$ the least element.

Comment: It seems like it would be cleaner to consider only sets $S$ which have **distinct** subset sums.  If you do care about coincidences such as $A+B=C$, then you will need to include another ordering to include these ties.  If you consider such cases to be covered by the other two combinations, then it is sufficient to just consider those sets which produce only strict inequalities (a simple perturbation argument proves the equivalence of formulations).

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer, but in order to get you started:

At least for small $N$ you can read off the cases from the [Hasse diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram). E.g. for your example $N=3$ we have

$$\begin{matrix}
  & & & & A+B+C \\
  & & & \huge\diagup & \\
  & & B+C \\
  & & \huge| & & \\
  & & A+C \\
  & \huge\diagup & & \huge\diagdown \\
C & &  & & A+B \\
  & \huge\diagdown & & \huge\diagup & \\
  & & B & & \\
  & & \huge| & & \\
  & & A & & \\
\end{matrix}$$

(where I've broken the symmetry because the hack I'm using to draw the diagram with MathJax has limitations around padding).

You can immediately see that the only incomparable elements are $A+B$ and $C$, and there are two ways to order two elements.

For $N=4$ it's more complicated:

$$\begin{matrix}
  & &   &                & \mkern-36mu A+B+C+D \mkern-36mu & & & & \\
  & &   &                & \huge| & & \\
  & &   &                & B+C+D & & & & \\
  & &   &                & \huge| & & \\
  & &   &                & A+C+D & & & & \\
  & &   & \huge\diagup & & \huge\diagdown & & \\
  & & C+D &                & & & A+B+D \\
  & &   & \huge\diagdown & & \huge\diagup & & \huge\diagdown \\
  & &   &                & B+D & & & & A+B+C \\
  & & & \huge\diagup & & \huge\diagdown & & \huge\diagup \\
  & & A+D & & & & B+C \\
  & \huge\diagup & & \huge\diagdown & & \huge\diagup \\
D & &  & & A+C \\
  & \huge\diagdown & & \huge\diagup & & \huge\diagdown \\
  & & C & & & & A+B \\
  & &   & \huge\diagdown & & \huge\diagup & \\
  & &   &                & B & & \\
  & &   &                & \huge| & & \\
  & & & & A & & \\
\end{matrix}$$

The choices are not all independent. E.g. $A+B$ vs $C$ is the same choice as $C+D$ vs $A+B+D$, because there's an obvious symmetry: $x < y$ iff $A+B+C+D - x > A+B+C+D - y$. (You may wish to add $0$ to the diagrams to emphasise the symmetry).

More subtlely, the choices are no longer binary. $D$ is incomparable to the entire chain $A + C < B + C < A + B + C$, so there are four places we can insert it into the chain, and they make it collapse in different ways.

- If $D < A + C$ we're left with two decisions: $A + B$ vs $C < D$; and $A+D$ vs $B+C$.
- If $A + C < D < B + C$ we're left with two decisions: $C$ vs $A+B$ and $B+C$ vs $A + D$.
- If $B + C < D < A + B + C$ we're left with one decision: $C$ vs $A+B$.
- If $A + B + C < D$ we again have the one decision $C$ vs $A+B$.

All of the remaining decisions are independent, so there are 14 possible chains.

---

I did the above diagrams by hand. If you want to construct them algorithmically then you can do a [transitive reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_reduction) from a set of simple but not minimal relations. Calling the values $A_1, A_2, \ldots A_N$:

- For each element $A_i + A_j + \ldots + A_m$, we remove in turn each variable $A_j$ and replace it with $A_k$ choosing the smallest $k > j$ such that $A_k$ is not already included. Then $A_i + A_j + \ldots + A_m < A_i + A_k + \ldots + A_m$.
- For each element $A_i + A_j + \ldots + A_m$ which doesn't include $A_1$, we add $A_1$. Then $A_i + A_j + \ldots + A_m < A_1 + A_i + A_j + \ldots + A_m$.

This gives a sparse graph, so the transitive reduction can be done in $2^N N$ time.

However, if you want to automate this rather than have a manual step, it may be simpler to construct the full transitive closure in $2^{3N}$ time (or slightly faster if you want to use a more complex matrix multiplication algorithm) and read off the incomparable pairs directly rather than reconstructing them from the forks in the transitive reduction.